# How to use reduce() on a list and get a dictionary?

Tags: python, reduce

I'm trying to create a dictionary of word stems where the stems are the key and the value is the array of words that have the key as their stem. I've tried the following code

```
stem_word_dictionary = reduce(
        lambda accumulator, word_stem_tuple:
        accumulator.setdefault(word_stem_tuple[1], []).append(word_stem_tuple[0]),
        word_stem_tuple_list,
        {})
```

I get this error:

```
accumulator.setdefault(word_stem_tuple[1], []).append(word_stem_tuple[0]),
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

I don't understand what's happening here. I'm using an empty dictionary as the starting value for the reduce so not sure why it's "NoneType". Also disclaimer: I'm super new to python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reduction function used for `reduce` should always return an object of the same type as its input object, so that it can continue its reduction operation with the resulting object and the next object from the iterator. Your `lambda` function currently calls `dict.setdefault()`, a function that always returns `None`, so it naturally results in an error when it tries the next reduction operation with a `None` object.

For your purpose you should use the following loop instead of a reduction function:

```
stem_word_dictionary = {}
for w, k in word_stem_tuple_list:
    stem_word_dictionary.setdefault(k, []).append(w)
```

Comment: oh sorry that print was left in there from debugging

Comment: I see. The problem is the same though. I've updated my answer to note the different function you use.

Comment: I see. I'm assuming there's no alternative function that returns the dictionary is there?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a recommended implementation.

Comment: `setdefault` doesn't return None - in this case it returns a list, and the None comes from the subsequent `list.append` call.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `append()` function does not return the list it is given. `reduce()` works by feeding the result of the previous invocation into the input of the next invocation. If the previous invocation does not return anything, it gets `None`, which is what the value of `accumulator` is following the first call.

Hop into any python REPL and do a simple:

```
a = []
a.append(1)
```

See how there is no output?